# How PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) is different from AWS (Amazon Web Services)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry, pcf

Pivotal gives you option to deploy your application with help of Cloud Foundry inside AWS Cloud.  I am little confused how PCF and AWS are differ.  I know that PCF gives solution using which host (client) can make their own cloud on-premises.

AWS do not provide anything like that.  And has lot of other services for elasticity, agility and scalability.

But these two are huge in terms of offerings.  Please help in differentiating these two.

Comment: Question suppose to be AWS Elastic Beanstalk / Pivotal Cloud Foundry?

Answer (score 29):

PCF is a commercial cloud platform (product) built by Pivotal on top of open source Cloud Foundry. PCF can be deployed on [AWS, GCP, OpenStack, VMware vSphere, and some other IaaS platforms](https://pivotal.io/en/platform#unified).

You should consider using PCF if you want to run your own cloud platform and you don't want to start from scratch.

When using PCF, you can deploy, configure and operate other [products provided by Pivotal and their partners](https://pivotal.io/platform/services-marketplace), or build your own ones based on your needs.

A typical use case for PCF is when companies want to deploy their applications on-premises for any reason (cost efficiency, flexibility, legal regulations, control over infrastructure, etc.). In this case they decide to use PCF as a leverage to build and operate their own (private) cloud offering. Another use case is when companies don't want to depend on the underlaying IaaS infrastructure. In this scenario, they rely on the fact PCF is IaaS agnostic to give them the ability to migrate if they need to.

Answer (score 11):

These can help you in finding the real difference between PCF and AWS.
https://aws.amazon.com/types-of-cloud-computing/

https://cloudacademy.com/blog/cloud-foundry-benefits/

In two line:

PCF - can be used as PaaS -[Platform as a Service]

AWS - can be used as IaaS -[Infrastructure as a Service]

Answer (score 10):

So, technically Pivotal Cloud Foundry is a cloud abstraction framework. It's intention is to wrap preexisting commercial cloud offerings to allow adopters to be protected (to a degree) from solution lock-in (here meaning that, the PCF Cloud API is a mapping and abstraction layer over other cloud delivery systems. It's core advantage is that you can always choose the cheapest provider without needing to rebuild your delivery / deployment infrastructure.

It's basically a re-imaging of the HAL concept (if your familiar with that) but instead of enabling the choice of hardware with a single software solution, it enables choice of cloud.

Main reason for using PCF is to enable a person to advantage from competition. Cloud solution providers want to specifically seek to couple you to their particular flavor of system so it takes alot of effort to change away from them so that they can easily adjust their costs (e.g. increase prices) because customers are sufficiently dependent on their particular service and there is a cost for the customer to switch.

Pivotal may offer a cloud of their own, but the idea of the open source cloud foundry is to not force that choice on the business or consumer.

Answer (score 10):

**The most distinct difference between IaaS and PaaS is that IaaS offers administrators more direct control over operating systems, but PaaS offers users greater flexibility and ease of operation.**

[image]

**SaaS examples:** BigCommerce, Google Apps, Salesforce, Dropbox, MailChimp, ZenDesk, DocuSign, Slack, Hubspot.

**PaaS examples:** AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Heroku, Windows Azure (mostly used as PaaS), Force.com, OpenShift, Apache Stratos, Magento Commerce Cloud.

**IaaS examples:** AWS EC2, Rackspace, Google Compute Engine (GCE), Digital Ocean, Magento 1 Enterprise Edition*.

referece: [bigcommerce](https://www.bigcommerce.com/blog/saas-vs-paas-vs-iaas/#examples-of-saas-paas-and-iaas)